# PHP session_destroy on shown element

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I want to show a link to logout only if a user is logged in. Code from page.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
...
    <form class="navbar-right" id="user">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {echo '<li><a href="#">Logout here</a></li>';} ?>
      </ul>
    </form>
```

When user clicks the 'Logout here' I want him to destroy the session when the user clicks the 'Logout here' link.. How to use a PHP session_destroy() function, if I'm using PHP inside html? I was thinking about adding onclick to a href element, but it didn't work. Maybe Ajax? Thanks!

Comment: `page.php` would destroy the session, thats the logout link

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your above code -- assuming the user has a `$_SESSION` parameter called `login_user`, they will see the link to logout. You handle the destruction of the session on `page.php` -- you wouldn't be able to see the link to logout if you already destroyed the session ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to send a parameter and destroy the session. Put this in page.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST["logout"]){
        session_destroy();
    }
?>
```

And then set the hyperlink to `page.php?logout` instead of `page.php`.

Comment: Just added the code. After the php tag, you can add html to tell the user that they've successfully logged out.

Comment: No, this isn't it. The <li> element is shown only when the user is logged in. But how to make the user logout when he clicks the conditionally shown element?

Comment: By clicking on the link, it will take him to page.php, correct?

By having `<?php session_destroy(); ?>` in page.php, that will log the user out.

Comment: No, sorry - my fault. He already is on page.php and I want him to be able to log-out by clicking the 'Logout Here' link (in terms of destroying the session).

Comment: dont forget `session_start();` first